# defining redirecting route in ember causing other route to not work

Tags: ember.js

I have a route defined as:

```
AS.Router.map(function(){
    this.resource('analytics', {path: '/analytics'}, function(){
        this.route('index', {path: '/'});
        this.route('config', {path: '/config'});
    ); 
});

AS.AnalyticsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    redirect: function() {
        this.transitionTo('analytics.index');
    }
});
```

With above config, I am able to load pages :

## /#/analytics

--this loads the analytics/index template

## /#/analytics/config

--this loads the analytics/config template

but #/analytics/index doesn't load, it just shows the loading gif image. Here is how my templates look like :

## analytics:

```
{{outlet}}
```

## analytics\index:

```
index
```

## analytics\config:

```
config
```

Is there a way I could make url link to #/analytics/index work too without breaking #/analytics?

Thanks,
Dee

Comment: which version of ember are you using?

Comment: You shouldn't have to define an index `route` within a `resource`. It should be there by default. Look at the table provided here: http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_resources

Comment: I using ember v1.0.0-rc.6.1

Comment: @DeewendraShrestha, allright, check my answer, hope it helps you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define a `resource` in your router map then `analytics.index` is an implicit route and should not be defined explicit. The default behaviour is then that your `analytics.index` template will be rendered into your `analytics` template's outlet in the place where you have an `{{outlet}}` defined.

So for example this should work as expected:

```
AS.Router.map(function(){
  this.resource('analytics', {path: '/analytics'}, function(){
    this.route('config', {path: '/config'});
  ); 
});
```

This will render correctly the `analytics.index` template into the `analytics` template outlet.

If your `analytics` route should be directly accessible when navigating to `"/"` and you want your user to be redirected to `/analytics` then you should redirect from your `IndexRoute` instead:

```
AS.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  redirect: function() {
    this.transitionTo('analytics');
  }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response and the explanation, its much appreciated. Our project structure is such that I cannot modify the IndexRoute("#/analytics" loads one app and "#/reports" loads another independent app and so on). I guess at the end what I wanted was the url #/analytics and #/analytics/index to do exactly the same thing, although I know #/analytics will render the analytics/index template internally after all, but it seems like we can have only one URL pattern/route to work but not both simultaneously.